# C language pipe between 2 child processes blocks indefinitely

Tags: c, unix, named-pipes

I am trying to make a program to takes a command including pipes and then executes it. This is a simplified version of it where I'm trying to pipe the ls and wc command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(){     
   char* arglist1[] = {"ls", NULL};    // writing process
   char* arglist2[] = {"wc", NULL};    // reading process

   int pipefd[2]; 
   pid_t p1, p2;

   if (pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
      printf("\nPipe could not be initialized");
      return 0;
   }
   
   p1 = fork();
   if (p1 < 0) {
      printf("\nCould not fork");
      return 0;
   }
   if (p1 == 0) {       // Child 1 executing it needs to write at the write end
      close(pipefd[0]);
      dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
      close(pipefd[1]);

      if (execvp(arglist1[0], arglist1) < 0) {
         printf("\nCould not execute command 1..");
         exit(0);
   }
   } else {             // Parent executing
      p2 = fork();
      if (p2 < 0) {
         printf("\nCould not fork");
         return 0;
      }
      if (p2 == 0) {    // Child 2 executing it needs to read at the read end
         close(pipefd[1]);
         dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
         close(pipefd[0]);
         if (execvp(arglist2[0], arglist2) < 0) {
             printf("\nCould not execute command 2..");
             exit(0);
         }
      } else {          // parent executing, waiting for two children
         wait(NULL);    
         wait(NULL);
      }
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Although there is error handling in the program, it neither shows anything nor ends. Where is it blocking?

Comment: Error messages age should be written to `stderr` and should end with a newline (and don't normally need to start with a newline).

Comment: You don't need to test return value of the `exec*()` functions.  If they succeed, they don't return; if they return, they failed.

Comment: Your problem is that the parent process does not close the pipe so the `wc` command does not get EOF (because the parent could write to it), so it doesn't exit.

Comment: When does the parent need to close it, Before the return statement in the main function?

Comment: The parent process should close the pipe before waiting for the children.

Comment: Yes the close(pipefd[0]) and close(pipefd[1]) call before the parent waits solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the parent doesn't close both the pipe's file descriptors, and the `wc` process won't die until it gets EOF on the pipe, and that won't happen until every process that has the write end of the pipe open has closed it.  You need to close both ends of the pipe in the parent before waiting for the children to die.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

---

If the parent process will not communicate with any of its children via
the pipe, it must ensure that it closes both ends of the pipe early
enough (before waiting, for example) so that its children can receive
EOF indications on read (or get SIGPIPE signals or write errors on
write), rather than blocking indefinitely.
Even if the parent uses the pipe without using `dup2()`, it should
normally close at least one end of the pipe — it is extremely rare for
a program to read and write on both ends of a single pipe.

Note that the `O_CLOEXEC` option to
[`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
and the `FD_CLOEXEC` and `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` options to `fcntl()` can also factor
into this discussion.

If you use
[`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html)
and its extensive family of support functions (21 functions in total),
you will need to review how to close file descriptors in the spawned process
([`posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addclose.html),
etc.).

Note that using `dup2(a, b)` is safer than using `close(b); dup(a);`
for a variety of reasons.
One is that if you want to force the file descriptor to a larger than
usual number, `dup2()` is the only sensible way to do that.
Another is that if `a` is the same as `b` (e.g. both `0`), then `dup2()`
handles it correctly (it doesn't close `b` before duplicating `a`)
whereas the separate `close()` and `dup()` fails horribly.
This is an unlikely, but not impossible, circumstance.

---

Side notes:

1. Error messages should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and should end with a newline.  They don't normally need to start with a newline.
2. You don't need to test the return value from the `exec*()` family of functions.  If they succeed, they don't return; if they return, they failed.  But it is important to have code after the `eec*()` call to trap the error.
3. The program should exit with a non-zero status (e.g. `EXIT_FAILURE`) if the `exec*()` function fails.  Exiting with status zero reports success.